# How to add wildcard to SOSL variable binding

Tags: dynamic-sosl, parameterizedsearch

I am doing a LWC search component that is handled by a SOSL query. Currently i am sending the `searchTerm` and creating a dynamic SOSL query that is executed by `Search.query(queryString)` method.
In the end the i have something that looks like this:

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

queryString = 'FIND :searchTerm IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Id, Name, PersonEmail ..... )'

List<List<sObject>> searchList = Search.query(query);

if (!searchList.isEmpty()) {
    accounts = (Account[]) searchList[0];
}
```

The issue is that i am trying to add a wildcard (*) to the search term, but it does not provide the desired results whatever i try. I think the parameter binding is always escaping the wildcard character. Is there a way to add wildcard with parameter binding, because i really don't want to rely on the user sends and put it directly there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with below code:-

```
string searchTerm = '*Edge*';
string queryString = 'FIND :searchTerm IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Id, Name)';
List<List<sObject>> searchList = Search.query(queryString);
system.debug('searchList '+searchList);
```

It returned when executed from annonymous window

[image]

To make it work with lwc, I did in this way:-

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import method4 from '@salesforce/apex/SampleApexClass.method4';

export default class ApexImperativeMethod extends LightningElement {
    search = '*edge*';

    connectedCallback() {
        method4({ str : this.search})
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error in sezrch',error);
            });
    }
}
```

and method was like this:-

```
@auraenabled
public static List<List<sObject>> method4(string str){
    string searchTerm = str;
    string queryString = 'FIND :searchTerm IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Id, Name)';
    List<List<sObject>> searchList = Search.query(queryString);
    system.debug('searchList '+searchList);
    return searchList;
}
```

and i can see the result as:-

[image]

so, add the wildcard in search term in js itself and it will work.